# Generating Power Set of a String Recursively in Java

Tags: java, recursion

I'm trying to do recursive implementation of a Power Set generator working off of some pseudocode I was given, but when given a string like "abc", rather than having sets

{}, {a}, {b}, {c}, {a,b}, {a,c}, {b,c}, and {a,b,c},

I get {}, {0}, {1}, {2}, {0,1}, etc.

```
public static ArrayList GenerateSubsets(String setString) {
      ArrayList A = new ArrayList<String>();
      ArrayList temp = new ArrayList<String>();
      if(setString.length() > 0) {
         temp = GenerateSubsets(setString.substring(0,setString.length() - 1));
         for(int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Temp i: "+temp.get(i));
            A.add(temp.get(i));
            A.add(temp.get(i) + " " + (setString.length() - 1));
         }
         return A;
      }
      else
         A.add("");
         return A;
   }
```

This is based directly on the pseudocode, why isn't it working correctly?

Edit: This is the test

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  ArrayList one = GenerateSubsets("abcd");
  for(int i = 0; i < one.size(); i++) {
     System.out.print(one.get(i)+ ", ");
     if(i%5 == 0) {
        System.out.println("");
     }
  }
```

}

And I get output of (without the line breaks)

, 
 3,  2,  2 3,  1,  1 3, 
 1 2,  1 2 3,  0,  0 3,  0 2, 
 0 2 3,  0 1,  0 1 3,  0 1 2,  0 1 2 3,

Comment: What does the `println` statement print? Does it print the right values?

Comment: I added the test and output above

Comment: You seem to be adding the indices instead of the values at those indices.

Answer (score 1):

Statement `(setString.length() - 1)` gives you the index of char. And by concatenating it you receive a Power set of indexes. You need use `setString.charAt(setString.length()-1)` to receive char at given position.

Comment: I just received an edited version of the pseudocode and changing that line solves my problem. Thanks!

Comment: P.S. Also, for me, manipulating directly string with `substring()` and `charAt()` not best practice. In my opinion, manipulating the array of char will be better.